# How solving Problem installing the noise package

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, noise, perlin-noise

I tried to install noise Python package, but I encountered this error

`
PS C:\Users\MacBook\Desktop\python-superhi> python -m pip install noise
Collecting noise
Using cached noise-1.2.2.zip (132 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: noise
Building wheel for noise (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [14 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\noise
copying perlin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\noise
copying shader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\noise
copying shader_noise.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\noise
copying test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\noise
copying **init**.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\noise
running build_ext
building 'noise._simplex' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for noise
Running setup.py clean for noise
Failed to build noise
Installing collected packages: noise
Running setup.py install for noise ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for noise did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [16 lines of output]
running install
C:\Users\MacBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
warnings.warn(
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\noise
copying perlin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\noise
copying shader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\noise
copying shader_noise.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\noise
copying test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\noise
copying **init**.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\noise
running build_ext
building 'noise._simplex' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> noise

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
`

please help me to solve this

Answer (score -3):

It is always better to use PyCharm IDE for python projects because it is easy to download modules and to setup environment.
you can download this IDE here: [download](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).